# Dynamically change cursor style for certain databound datalist items?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a `datalist` that is bound to a `datatable` that looks like this:

```
EmpId    RoomNum
A230     201
A235     202
null     203
F520     204
null     205
```

As you can see some RoomNums don't have an EmpId. These are the items that will have the cursor style changed to the "hand". The datalist items with an EmpId will have the "No" cursor style. This only applies to the datalist.

And here's my datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListThumb" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="padding: 8px;width:72px;height:72px">
        <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick='<%# "return ShowRoom(" + Eval("RoomNum") + ");" %>'>
            <div style='width:72px;height:72px; background-image:url(<%# Eval("image_path") %>)'>
                <div style="width: 72px; padding-top: 3px; overflow: hidden;">
                    <div style="text-align: left; width:72px; float:left;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CommandName="cmd_RoomNum" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' 
                        runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RoomNum")%>' Font-Size="11pt"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

So how can I change the cursor style dynamically in the datalist items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a couple things here:

Add the following CSS classes:

```
.noEmpId {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.validEmpId {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then, I assume you want the cursor style on your LinkButton, so do something like this in your LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass='<%# Eval("EmpId") == null ? "noEmpId" : "validEmpId" %>' id="LinkButton1"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This doesn't keep anyone from clicking the button though. If you want to do that then you'd need to something like..

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick='<%# Eval("EmpId") == null ? "return false;" : "return ShowRoom(" + Eval("RoomNum") + ");" %>' id="LinkButton1"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Nice addition to change the `Enabled` property.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added `Enabled='<%# Eval("ClientId") == null ? "false" : "true" %>'` to the `LinkButton`, but I get compilation error `Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'`. What could the issue be? `ClientId` is of type `int`.

Comment: Ah sorry, try removing the quotes around "false" and "true". It's trying to convert "false" or "true" (strings) to a bool which it's unable to do. Let me know if it works or not and I'll update the response. I don't get a compilation error when I remove them now at least.

Comment: I did find an issue. It seems that the `LinkButton.Enabled` property doesn't affect `OnClientClick`. So it can be set to false but `OnClientClick` is still executed.

Comment: Oops didn't realize you had an OnClientClick in there. You should be able to take what I have in the OnClientClick Method and do something like the following. I'll update my answer actually. return false should keep the client side code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can control what the cursor looks like through css. You could define the following two classes in your css.

```
.cursor-hand { cursor: pointer }
.cursor-no { cursor: not-allowed }
```

And then you could conditionally apply the class to your item. It's a bit convoluted. But you could define a method in your code behind like so:

```
public string GetStyle(string empId) 
{
    return empId == null ? "cursor-hand" : "cursor-no";
}
```

And then in your `ItemTemplate` somewhere, not sure for which element.

```
<div class='<%# GetStyle(Eval("empId")) %>' ...> ... </div>
```

I hope this answers your question.

That being said, I am not sure if this will exactly accomplish the desired result. Just because a cursor is 'NO' does not mean you can't click on an item.